# How to print input and output from parse, rewrite, plan and execute process in PostgreSQL's from postgres.c?

Tags: c, postgresql

I would like to print the input and output from PostgreSQL process like the parse, rewrite, plan and execute process from the PostgreSQL source code in `postgresql-11.1/src/backend/tcop/postgres.c`.  I have tried to use `printf()` but I still get an error. Please help me.

Comment: Do you need something that exceeds `debug_print_parse`, `debug_print_rewritten` and `debug_print_plan`? Can you describe your requirements in some detail?

Comment: when we querying such as "select * from my_table;" the query should be passed parse. rewritten, plan and execute process. so, i would like to show the result of every step (parse. rewritten, plan and execute).

Comment: where we can see the print out of the process ?

Comment: I the PostgreSQL log file.

Comment: where we can see the log file ?

Comment: That is determined by the configuration parameters `log_directory` and `log_filename`. I am surprised that you want to hack the server when you can't even find that information in the documentation.

Comment: i have tried that way, and actually there is no 'pg_log' in "/usr/local/pgsql/data", then i try to create "pg_log" directory after configuring the parameter. but sill, the logfile doesn't exist. also, i have checked in home/postgres/logfile.But in the log file, there is no activity that i had done.

Comment: I'm sorry if I do not know many things in postgres,  actually i'm still newbee here.

Comment: Perhaps you are using Debian or Ubuntu Linux, where the packagers decided to handle this is a (for PostgreSQL) unusual way. If I remember correctly, the logs are in `/var/log/postgresql` on these distributions.

Comment: I use Ubuntu Linux. I ever open /var/log/postgresql-11-main.log. But for the second trial, I don't have permission anymore to open that file.

Comment: You should learn the basics of Linux file system permissions. Become `root` and you can read everything (not that this is good advice in general, but it seems to be a play system anyway).

Comment: actually, i've found the logfile. I run the postgres from the source code and the log file is in home/postgres. But, the logfile just show the error action not the whole  transaction. You're right that I have to  learn much about the basic of all of this.

Comment: Yes, but if you enable the parameters I wrote in my first comment in `postgresql.conf` and reload or restart the server, you will get that information in the log.